# Como definir a largura das colunas em uma planilha Excel gerada como HTML?

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, tabela-html

Preciso converter uma tabela HTML e gerar o arquivo em excel.
Como definir a largura das colunas no excel?
Crio o arquivo HTML usando o PHP e exporto usando :

```
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"" );
header ("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data" );
```

A questão é que não consigo definir a formatação da largura das colunas no excel. No CSS a tabulação está correta mas como formatar as larguras das colunas no excel?

Comment: Acho que não tem como, só gerando um arquivo XLS nativo. Já tentou exportar HTML puro ou CSV para ver o que rola?

Comment: sim, mesmo assim ele perde a formatação.

Comment: Na verdade você não está exportando para Excel, só está forçando que o browser sugira que o arquivo seja aberto pelo Excel. Talvez você precise gerar um arquivo Excel de verdade, usando HTML existem várias limitações de formatação (mas não tenho certeza de que esta seja uma delas).

Comment: conhece alguma api tipo worksheet.php pra fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Como sugerido pelo comentário do @bfavaretto, você está apenas forçando o browser a sugerir que a melhor forma de carregar um arquivo seja com o excel. Caso você queira setar a largura da coluna dessa forma, é possível criar um `xls` e renomeá-lo para um zip, daí basta abrir o `xml` e verificar as propriedades dele.

No entanto, talvez seja interessante você dar uma olhada na biblioteca [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), que é uma biblioteca bem famosa para a manipulação de arquivos `xls`. No caso da PHPExcel, basta utilizar o comando para setar a largura, como pode ser visto no exemplo a seguir:

```php
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(0.54);
```

Caso você queira que a largura seja definida automaticamente, é possível utilizar:

```php
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, você quer abrir um HTML dentro do Excel.

Ao invés de se preocupar em settar a largura através de PHP, porque você não parte para uma macro no Excel?

Já usei bastante a macro abaixo. Adaptei para você.

**Veja o comando Adjust Column Width. Ele não irá settar larguras específicas, mas vai otimizar as larguras em geral.**

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
               "URL;file:///C:/test.html" _
    , Destination:=Range("$C$3"))
    .Name = "test"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Crédito para mcbranco que me ajudou no fórum da Microsoft em 2011.
http://goo.gl/KxGxwl